# Set Symfony2 To Not Store Session Data

Tags: session, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app representing a restful application that has no need for persistent sessions.

For each request to the application, given the default session configuration, and given that the client ignores the session cookie, a new session file is created in the default session save path of `app/cache/<env>/sessions`.

The app receives many requests per day resulting in a very large volume of unwanted session files. Running `rm -Rf app/cache/prod/session/*` takes minutes to complete.

I would prefer if the app did not store any session data.

I have tried setting the application configuration session save path to `/dev/null` or `/dev/null/sessions` but this results an exception either due to the directory already existing (for `/dev/null`) or due to the specified path being not a directory (for `/dev/null/<anything>`).

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path: /dev/null
```

The best I can see I can do from reading the [session documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html) is to invalidate the session, which clears all session attributes and regenerates the session ID. This doesn't get me to a state of there being no session and no persistent session file.

Can I get Symfony2 to not store any session data for a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own Session handler and replace `session` service alias with it:

```
services:
    session:
        class: Path\To\Your\Session\Class
```

You can check implementation with standard session class `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session`